# after specific seconds android request to the servlet for retrieving the new data if new data is available

Tags: android

i just creating an android ap. so in that i created a connection with http to servlet. but i want that request is pass automatic after few seconds. so help me to find solution.

this is my connector class

```
public String Intraday() { 
    String url = URL+"?flag="+"intra"; 
    httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 
    try{ 
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost); 
        int statuscode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
        if(statuscode == 200){ 
            String responceMsg = getResponse(httpResponse); 
            return responceMsg; 
        }else{ 
            return null; 
        } 
    }catch(ClientProtocolException e){ 
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e); 
    }catch (IOException e) { 
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e); 
    }    
    return null;
}
```

this is the class from i calling my connector class now tell me where i put the code of thread??

try
        {

```
        String str = Connector.getInstance().Intraday();  //now tell me where i write 

        String st = new String(str);    
        Log.e("Main",st);
        String[] rows  = st.split("_");
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
        tableLayout.removeAllViews();                       

        for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            String row  = rows[i];
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            final String[] cols = row.split(";");
            IntraThread popup = null;
            Handler handler = null;

            for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {

                final String col = cols[j];                                 
                final TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                columsView.setText(String.format("%7s", col));                              
                tableRow.addView(columsView);   

                if(j==0)
                {           
                    head= col;
                }
                if(j==2)
                {
                    price = Integer.parseInt(col);
                }
                if(j==4)
                {
                    target = Integer.parseInt(col);
                }

                if(j==5)
                {                       
                    handler = new Handler();                        
                    ltp = Integer.parseInt(col);                                
                    popup = new IntraThread(handler,head, target,ltp,price,Intraday.this,columsView);           

                }
                if(j==6){

                    popup.setColumnViewexit(columsView);
                    handler.postDelayed(popup, 300);
                }

            } 
            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);  
        }
    }                   

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Main",e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: @T0X1C: I've updated my question. Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is short of dummy code modify it to suit  your needs

```
    String str;
    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {            
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            while(true)
            {
                str = Connector.getInstance().Intraday();  //This is edited code
                Thread.sleep(few seconds);
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Replace the first line in Try `String str = Connector.getInstance().Intraday();  //now tell me where i write` with the code above provided

Comment: i modify my code. bt create fatal error of thread....My method in another class and i called it from another class.. so where i write this.. plz guide me..

Comment: You will write this code in the class from where you are calling the method and wrap Thread.sleep using try catch

Comment: I have changed the answer implement that if its still not clear reply I will try to make it more clearer to you

Comment: i just modify str as final.. bt "error The final local variable str cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"

Comment: 02-28 12:23:54.524: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: debug your code and tell on which line its appearing it simple related to some other problem not this one

Comment: android makes problem when handler is initilize in run() so i just initialize handler out of thread so now its working.... thank you so much.. really..